# create cumulative column based on conditions pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, cumulative-sum

I have dataframe with multiple columns. One of them is CumulativeProduction. Need to create another column called 'corrected Cummulative Column'. Please check below.

df:

[image]

My approach:

I tried to use forward fill to fill 0's but it fails if the column has multiple sets of values(like 100,200,300 in the below part). is there way to create fix this?

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'CummulativeProdution':[100,200,300,0,0,0,100,200,300,0,0,0]      
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: just use `.cumsum()`

Comment: @oskros it didn't give the desired output.  Please check the column again.

Comment: .cumsum() just gives the cumulative of the given column.

Comment: Here need to get cumulative, only if there are values after the 0's. Otherwise here cumsum() gives the cumulative of cumulative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to run cumsum() starting from the value before the first zero:

```
df['Corrected'] = df['CummulativeProdution']

mask = df['CummulativeProdution'] == 0

# if the series has zeros
if mask.any():
    # find the index of the first zero
    first_zero_idx = df[mask].index[0]
    # assuming monotonic increasing index
    before_zero_idx = first_zero_idx - 1
    df.loc[before_zero_idx:, 'Corrected'] = df.loc[before_zero_idx:, 'Corrected'].cumsum()
```

Comment: can also find the index with a one-liner: `before_zero_idx = mask.shift(-1).ffill().idxmax()` (though your version is more readable)